# brew install yvm --without-node fails

Tags: node.js, homebrew, yarnpkg

I am trying to install `yvm` on my computer using `brew`. As I already have `node` installed with `nmv` I would like to use the `--without-node` flag.

When I run `brew install yvm --without-node` it fails and prints the following:

```
==> node yvm.js configure-shell --yvmDir .
Last 15 lines from /Users/user/Library/Logs/Homebrew/yvm/01.node:
2020-03-30 18:25:53 -0700

node
yvm.js
configure-shell
--yvmDir
.
```

I checked the logs and they look the same outside of a bunch of system information.